# How to pass a condition via Data Attribute to JS for validation

Tags: jquery, validation

Eng has requested that I allow them to enter special validation conditions to be passed to our Generic Validator via a data attribute such as:

```
data-clv_special_condition="$(this).val()=='X'"
```

on the JS side I would need to capture that data attribute and plug it into our validation such as:

```
$('[data-clv_special_condition]').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('clv_special_condition')){ 
        //Do something 
    })
});
```

However as you can imagine something like this would not work. Can anyone offer up any solutions for passing a condition from data attribute to JS to be ran through validation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this exact problem in the past using a custom validation framework I built, though I don't think it would work for your case.

In your case, I think a simple `eval()` would work (even if inadvisable)?

```js
$('[data-clv_special_condition]').each(function(){
  var success = eval($(this).data('clv_special_condition'));
  if (!success) {
    console.log("doh!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-clv_special_condition="$(this).val() == 'Yes!';" value="No!" />
```

Comment: Added a functioning snippet.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. Anything can get injected and executed by your code this way.

Comment: @Jan - I agree, it's "inadvisable" (as I said) to use eval, though I don't see how this is more prone to JS injection than any other type of code?  The attribute would have to get rewritten somehow, which requires DOM manipulation (sandboxed).

Comment: If this comes from an external source, you could for example strip or escape `<` and `>` characters before outputting it for parsing in another manner. You could of course also do that with an `eval`solution, but if you end up using `eval` it doesn't matter. You've given your external partner control over your application rather than the other way around.

Comment: @Jan - By pushing a partner's content to your clients, you're already "giving them control" over your app.... Again, even your far-fetched concept doesn't ADD any security holes in this solution.

Comment: Giving control over content and configuration  is very different from giving control over code.

Comment: @Jan HTML content can include a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Jan - Furthermore, I explained that this is an inadvisable solution in my answer.  It is still the only correct answer to the question posed.

Comment: Yes, but since the user is asking for something that you shouldn't be doing, the correct answer is to advise them to do something else. "HTML content can include a `<script>` tag" that doesn't mean you have to allow it. Answering questions means solving the problem, not doing exactly what the asker asks. Same as when a client comes with a request of "doing this", "doing this" very seldom is what they really want/need.

Comment: @Jan - No. The **correct** answer to the question is `eval()` - just like `rm -rf *` would be to "how do I delete all files on Linux?" For the question posed by the OP, `eval` is the **simplest** solution, if inadvisable when designing a ground-up system (albeit NOT for the reason you suggested). Also, it gets his code working in seconds instead of weeks refactoring for a solution like the one below.   And it's NOT more susceptible to JS injection, per your fallacious post. I'm actually a little offended that you are oppressing me with your misdirected coding righteousness. You're flat wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than letting them set an entire expression, why not add a series of conditional data attributes with their own logic in your controller? Like

```
data-clv_equals="X" data-clv_notequals="Y" data-clv_regex="Z"
```

and in your validator something like

```
var isValid = true;

if ($(this).data('clv_equals')) {
   isValid &= $(this).data('clv_equals') === $(this).val();
}

if ($(this).data('clv_notequals')) {
    isValid &= $(this).data('clv_notequals') !== $(this).val();
}

if ($(this).data('clv_regex')) {
    var regex = new RegExp($(this).data('clv_regex'));
    isValid &= regex.test($(this).val());
}
```

It makes more sense both from a data perspective and from a logic perspective in your code. Separates the data from the logic and prevents you from having to parse an expression (with potentially dangerous ramifications).

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing something like that as well but they can get pretty dang complicated. And true I can solve for that as well.

Comment: Not only for the potential security risks of handing over that kind of control, also consider that one faulty expression could throw an error that breaks other code execution. I'd strongly advise against anything rather than parsing the expression yourself. But if you were to do that anyways, adding specific attributes would probably be a simpler approach. Another possibility would be allowing for a regular expression (which could still be one of the optional attributes with this approach).

Comment: Just wanted to give you an updated. This is working nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Adrianopolis - FYI, the solution I noted above that I built was more similar to this one. See: https://insurify.com/static/js/ensurify/forms/validation_rules.js (and form.js, input.js, validator.js).  An extensible collection of validation rules like this can handle most of your use-cases out of the box, and if you run into a case that it doesn't handle, you can just add on to the end of the list.  Although this obviously isn't the direct answer to your question, it is my suggestion for how to build form validation.

Answer (score 0):

What about saving just the name of the validator in the data attribute, like:

```
<input data-clv_special_condition="validatorOne" />
```

And storing the validation login in the js code, see:

```
var validators = {
  validatorOne: function(element) { ... },
  validatorTwo: function(element) { ... },
};

$('[data-clv_special_condition]').each(function(){
  var validatorName = $(this).data('clv_special_condition');
  if(validators[validatorName](this){ 
      //Do something 
  });
});
```

Comment: Something like this would probably work better with HTML syntax like `data-validate-validatorOne="Error message"`, no?  That way, you could have multiple validators per input. BTW, I think the goal he's trying to achieve is custom jQuery validation code in the attribute value itself.